# Facebook Lead Ads - Lead Sync to Salesforce

Tags: facebook, salesforce

How to sync the leads created through Facebook Leads Ads to Salesforce. There is a new release [here](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/category/marketing/) but nothing much is explained. Does it require Marketing API to be used to sync the leads in real time? I would like know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to sync leads from Facebook to Salesforce Sales Cloud, you definitely need to work with the FB Marketing API. >https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/v2.5#setting-up-realtime-updates

To my knowledge, there is a seamless integration with the Salesforce **Marketing Cloud**.